# What's causing "Windows Security" login prompt to occur for just one user?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-authentication, windows-server-2003

Details:

- ASP.NET webforms
- .NET 4.0
- Windows Authentication
- IIS 6
- Windows Server 2003 SP2

[image]

Only one user is having an issue connecting to this one virtual directory.  He says he sees this login form in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  He uses his Windows credentials and is unable to login.  He is able to access other websites hosted in other virtual directories on the same domain.  No others are experiencing this issue.  He says he was able to access the site just fine a few weeks ago.  What could be causing this dialog box to appear for just this user for just this site no matter what browser he's using?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's all of the user's web browsers, this points to something with the user's permissions on the server for that particular website.

If it worked before as the user states, perhaps you can ask your server admins if anything was changed regarding user permissions on the server a few weeks ago.

Another path to go down would be to see if the user (or desktop admins) has installed any software on his/her machine that would disallow or alter Windows authentication in the browser for this site.  This is far more unlikely than a simple user permissions issue on the server since he/she can still access other protected websites with Windows authentication, but it might be worth asking about if you've run out of options.

Yet another unlikely possibility would be a rule change on the user's network's firewall that would somehow disallow this user's IP address and Windows authentication to this website.  Again, super unlikely, but I wanted to cover the bases here.